# HTTP ERROR 500 (This error is magneto 2.1.6)-php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, magento2

Recently I have bought gosmart Venus theme. They have provided two ways to install the theme one is theme uploading on existing Magento installation and second is the quick installer.

I have tried both ways and getting Error 500. Which says something wrong with directory permission. I tried solution shared on multiple sites/ forums but none from these worked.

These are commands which I have executed;
chmod -R 0777 pub var app/etc
chmod -R 0755 index.php setup/

These command on SSH And I run these command throw putty

This is the error I am getting.

Please help me to fix it. My website address is www.myplan.pk.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to open the error display of php to get the error with your system. If it happens only this link,check the code with expression error